# How to update the existing values

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating an API where I'm inserting `product_id,` `Product_Size`, `quantity`, `product_name` in an array called `product-info`.

Now I want to update the other values when `product id` is already existing.
my code for insertion in controller:

```
   if(!empty($product_info1)){
    foreach ($product_info1 as $value) {
        $product_id = isset($value->product_id) ? $value->product_id : 0;
        $Product_Size = isset($value->Product_Size) ? $value->Product_Size : 0;
        $quantity = isset($value->quantity) ? $value->quantity : 0;
        $product_name = isset($value->product_name) ? $value->product_name : 0;

           if(  $ok = 1)
        $this->api_details_model->productinventory_track($product_id,$Product_Size,$quantity,$product_name);
         {

             $api_status="true";
             $api_message="Done";
         }
    // $this->api_details_model->checkProductid($product_id);

    }
   }
```

model:

```
function productinventory_track($product_id,$Product_Size='',$quantity='',$product_name='')
{

        if($product_id>=0)
        {

            $data = array('product_name'=>$product_name,'size_id'=>$Product_Size,'stock_count'=>$quantity,'product_id'=>$product_id);

            if($this->db->insert('product_inventory', $data)){ return true; }else{ return false; }

        }
```

please tell me the code for update

Comment: $this->db->where('column_name', $id);
$this->db->update('table_name', $data);

Comment: see this link http://www.formget.com/update-data-in-database-using-codeigniter

Comment: i have added the query in model.but how to call from controller?..

Comment: from controller use this $this->modelName->modelFunction($id, $data);

Comment: but i need to write some condition before calling to model.because i want to update only when its existing in database.otherwise insert

Comment: if(check_id_exist_in table){ // update} else { // insert}

Comment: and how to check if that id exists?because i m getting error

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
$productInfo = $this->db->api_details_model->get($product_id);

$productArray['product_name'] = 'yourValue';
$productArray['size_id']      = 'yourValue';
$productArray['stock_count']  = 'yourValue';

// Means that there is no product with that ID in the database
if($productInfo == null)
   $this->db->api_details_model->add($productArray);

// It was found an ID in the database
else
   $this->db->api_details_model->edit($product_id, $productArray);
```

Functions in model:

```
public function add($data)
{
   $this->db->insert('product_inventory', $data);
}

public function edit($id, $data)
{
   $this->db->where('id', $id)
            ->update('product_inventory', $data);
}

public function get($id)
{
   $this->db->where('id', $id);

   return $this->db->get('product_inventory')->row();
}
```

Comment: while using the above code for insertion,when i m trying to insert 2 or more than 2 arrays its getting inserted but in case of 1 array.its giving me 4 rows with no value.also i m running it as api using chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo/RestClient.html.can i set alert when product id already exists?

Comment: If it works with two or more arrays properly and if it doesn't with only one, than it's your loop problem not the code I wrote.

Comment: i know that.i was asking you problem